# local host getting added in prefix, when using NavLink in React router Dom for external link routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to route to an external link using the React Router Dom 6.4.
But, the problem is the local host path is getting added. Can someone confirm, why?

localhost:3000/#/http://www.saveur.com/article/Recipes/

instead of

just: http://www.saveur.com/article/Recipes/

**NavLink Code:**

Getting the link through API

```
<div className='recipe-intro'>
    <p className='cus-type'>{ Capitalize(recipieInfo.recipe.cuisineType[0])}</p>
    <NavLink 
     target='_blank' to={{  pathname: `${recipieInfo.recipe.url}`}} 
     className="item-link">{recipieInfo.recipe.label}
     </NavLink> 
     <NutriInfo recipieInfo = {recipieInfo} />              
</div>
```

**Routing:**

Separate Component for Routes.

```
<div className="main-container for-routes">
  <Routes>
      <Route index path='/' element = {<LandingPage />} />
  </Routes>
</div>
```

**React Hashrouter:**

Using Hashrouter from React router dom

```
<React.StrictMode>
    <HashRouter>
       <Level1Boundary>
           <App />
       </Level1Boundary>
    </HashRouter>
</React.StrictMode>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `react-router-dom` `NavLink` component doesn't handle external links; it's used only to navigate to pages your app is rendering routes for. If you want or need to link to an external resource then use a regular anchor (`<a href>`) tag element.

If you want you can create a custom `NavLink` component that tests if the passed `to` prop is a valid external URL and conditionally render an anchor `<a>` tag or the RRD `NavLink` component. In the following example I've used the [is-url](https://github.com/segmentio/is-url) to validate a URL string.

Example:

```
import { NavLink as BaseNavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import isURL from "is-url";

const NavLink = ({ children, to, ...props }) => {
  return isURL(to) ? (
    <a href={to} {...props}>
      {children}
    </a>
  ) : (
    <BaseNavLink to={to} {...props}>
      {children}
    </BaseNavLink>
  );
};
```

```
<NavLink to="/test">Test</NavLink>
<NavLink to="http://www.saveur.com/article/Recipes/">External Test</NavLink>
```

[image: Edit local-host-getting-added-in-prefix-when-using-navlink-in-react-router-dom-for-e]